# ACF repeater field - If one row, show a static image

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have an ACF repeater field which pulls in images to an image slider.

if the user uploads just the one image the slider breaks.

So i need to count the repeater fields and then show two outputs.. One as a slider and one as a static image (if only one row)

here is my code so far:

```
    <div class="full-img-slider">

        <?php while( have_rows('top_images') ): the_row(); 

            $image = get_sub_field('image');

            ?>

                <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>">

            <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>
    <!-- Close full image slider -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

is there a way of saying if over 2 rows echo this?

I am not very PHP savvy.

Answer (score 1):

Using the help from Danjah and tweaking it.

I ended up with this, it works perfectly. Displays a static image if only one row and then displays a slider if more than one image.

```
<?php
$top_images = get_field('top_images');
$top_images_count = count($top_images);

if( $top_images_count > 1 ): ?>


        <?php if( have_rows('top_images') ): ?>

            <div class="full-img-slider">

                <?php while( have_rows('top_images') ): the_row(); 
                    $image = get_sub_field('image');
                    ?>

                        <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>">

                    <?php endwhile; ?>

            </div>

        <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- Close full image slider -->


        <?php else : ?>
        <!-- If only have one image do the below -->



        <?php if( have_rows('top_images') ): ?>


                <?php while( have_rows('top_images') ): the_row(); 
                    $image = get_sub_field('image');
                    ?>
                        <div class="content-area">
                            <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>">
                        </div>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>


        <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- Close full image slider -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this around your existing code:

```
<?php
$top_images = get_field('top_images');
$top_images_count = count($top_images);

if ( $top_images_count > 1 ) {

//YOUR EXISTING CODE HERE

}
?>
```

Then you need to add an elseif rule to display a static image if just one image has been added.

```
} elseif ( $top_images_count == 1 ) {
  //DISPLAY IMAGE
}
```

Read more her: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/code-examples/

Comment: I tried this, and its not working.. the page isnt loading, is this correct?
https://jsfiddle.net/oLz2qqr9/

Answer (score 0):

```
// get the count on the repeater field
// mabye use get_sub_field() instead of get_field() if it's nested
$count = count( get_sub_field( 'the_field' ) );

// begin $count conditions
if ( $count > 1 ) { 
the_field( 'great_than_1' );
 } else {
 the_field( 'less_than_1' ); 
 }
```

may be it will help..

https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/if-repeater-field-has-1-rows-2-rows-etc/